# How can I inspect a webpage without opening it in a browser?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

In a certain webpage that I was inspecting I saw some redirect links that didn't redirect directly to that link. For example: A button says "Go to Google" and then opened "www.examplesite.com/redirect_google" instead of just opening Google via `<href>`.

I wasn't sure if I trusted that link so a question came up: "How can I inspect that page to know what kind of scripts they do there?". But as you already understood I can't open it in my browser because I get redirected, so where can I type it so it inspects the page instantly?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: It is if I need a command line or some specific software with scripting

Comment: Command line and using softwares are not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the redirect is implemented at the network layer, then there's no page to inspect; it's just a http 301 response (or 302, etc.)

If the redirect is via a meta tag or Javascript, then you can request the page via curl without rendering the HTML or having a browser act upon the meta redirect.

In the case of Javascript, you could also disable JS in your browser (methods of how to do that vary depending on the browser you're using).

Answer (score 0):

Using CURL in command line on the given page, you will get the source code of the page.

Added to another programming language you can simply parse the files to check if it contains a redirect.

I'm also pretty sure a few tools exist over the Internet to check such behavior on websites, but I don't know any.

Answer (score 0):

Linux/UNIX command line:

```
$ curl -i www.example.com/redirect_google
```

There are many variations of this; some small utility that downloads content from URLs without caring about what the content is and showing you information about the responses (here `-i` to show HTTP headers).

But if your concern is that the page may not be trustworthy... well, why this Google redirect page in particular? *Any* site could try to attack you with some "bad content"...

Answer (score 0):

You can download the whole html file or whatever is stored there with tools like [WinHTTrack](http://www.chip.de/downloads/WinHTTrack_13008895.html) or [WSSniffer](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/wssniffer.html) for example.